# Meteor: insert failed: Access denied. No allow validators set on restricted collection for method 'insert'

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor

Hello I am working on a Meteor-React project and fairly new in this. I am trying to insert new object into existing collection but it shows error as indicated in the title.

This is my component responsible for inserting new item at the UI level.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import newTask from '../api/create'

export default Create = () => {
  const [task, createTask] = useState('');
  handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
      newTask(task)
    }
}
return (
<form className="add-task" noValidate="">
  <div>
    <div className="fieldset add-task-input fieldset-stripped">
      <div className="fieldset-content">
        <label className="fieldset-label">
          <span className="fieldset-label-content has-icon">
            <i className="icon-plus" />
          </span>
          <input
            className=""
            name="title"
            placeholder="Add new task"
            type="text"
            autoComplete="off"
            value={task}
            onChange={(e) => { createTask(e.target.value)}}
            onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
          />
        </label>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 )
}
```

This is the method that I am trying to export and import into the component file above.

```
import { Tasks } from '../../tasks';

export default newTask = (taskTitle) => Tasks.insert({
  title: taskTitle,
  dueDate: null,
  repeat: {},
  color: '#4e42c3',
  status: 'incomplete',
  customFields: []
})
```

I have tried using methods proposed by others as below, by adding the code below into the method file above:

```
Tasks.allow({
  insert: function () {
    return true;
  }
})
```

But still it does not work and show the same error. Any idea how to enable inserting new item into the Mongo Collection ?

Answer (score 1):

So previously I added the code below

```
Tasks.allow({
  insert: function () {
    return true;
  }
})
```

at the client side. Once I moved it to server side, it solves my problem.

Comment: This is strongly discouraged: https://blog.meteor.com/meteor-allow-deny-vulnerability-disclosure-baf398f47b25

Answer (score 1):

The allow/deny is opening a [security vulnerability](https://blog.meteor.com/meteor-allow-deny-vulnerability-disclosure-baf398f47b25). You may rather use it only for prototyping / mocking some initial software prototypes.

The correct way to update collections is to use [Meteor methods](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html):

*server*

```
import { Tasks } from '../path/to/tasks'

Meteor.methods({
  'insertTask': function ({ title, dueDate, repeat, color, status, customFields }) {
    return Tasks.insert({ title, dueDate, repeat, color, status, customFields })
  }
})
```

*client*

```
import { Tasks } from '../../tasks';

export default newTask = (taskTitle) => Meteor.call('insertTask', {
  title: taskTitle,
  dueDate: null,
  repeat: {},
  color: '#4e42c3',
  status: 'incomplete',
  customFields: []
})
```

Edit: If you only want to insert the document at the UI level and never have a collection on the server stored, you may make the Task collection local by exporting it wihtout a name:

*client*

```
export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using autopublish package?
Your trying to insert the object from the client side. Without autopublish package you can't do it. Either add autopublish or insert from the server side.

Comment: I was trying to follow this https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/forms-and-events. There is no mention of the needs of using autopublish package.

Comment: Share your repo, i will help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have solved it by putting the last piece of code above under server side. it solved the issue :) Thanks for your help anyway.